# How many positive integers $n$ are there such that $(7n + 1)$ is a perfect square and $(3n + 1) < 2008$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

> How many positive integers $n$ are there such that $(7n + 1)$ is a perfect square and $(3n + 1) < 2008$ ?

**What I Tried**: We have $(3n + 1) < 2008$
$\rightarrow n < 669$ . 
Now, $(7n + 1) = k^2$ for some $k$ .
$$\rightarrow 7n = (k + 1)(k - 1)$$
Now I have to count all the $n$ so that after multiplied by $7$ , gives a product same as the product of $2$ consecutive numbers with a gap of one. I know that $n = 5,9$ are two solutions, but there are more values so that when multiplied by $7$ gives a valid solution, like $k = 24,32$ .

The problem I am facing is, is there any elegant way here to count all the solutions? 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: **Beware** that there is an error in the answer you accepted - see my comment there.

Comment: Checked, also understood that there are overcounts.

Comment: *Possible* overcount - see the linked answers in ny comment there for more on this common logical gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, $7n = (k + 1)(k - 1)$

So $7$ is a factor of either $(k+1)$ or $(k-1)$

which means $k = 7 a -1$ or $7a+1$.

If $k = 7a - 1$, $n = 7a^2 - 2a \lt 669$ as you observed.

Taking $a = 1, 2, ...$ you get the values but if you only have to count the number of solutions, it is easy to see that $a \leq 9$ given the constraint $n \lt 669$.

Similarly take $k = 7a + 1$ and see how many solutions given the constraint of $n \lt 669$.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Since $n\le 668$, we know that $7n+1\le 4677$. $\left\lfloor\sqrt{4677}\right\rfloor=68$, so we want to know how many of the integers $1,2,\ldots,68$ have squares of the form $7n+1$. Suppose that $7n+1=k^2$ for some integer $k$; then $k^2\equiv 1\pmod 7$, and it’s easy to check that this is the case precisely when $k\equiv 1\pmod 7$ or $k\equiv -1\pmod 7$, i.e., when $k=7m\pm 1$ for some integer $m$.

There are $9$ positive multiples of $7$ less than $68$, each of which provides two such values of $k$.

> E.g., $3\cdot 7=21$ means that $k=20$ and $k=22$ will work: $20^2=400=7\cdot 57+1$, and $22^2=484=7\cdot 69+1$.

Thus, there are altogether $2\cdot9=18$ such integers $n$.

Comment: The proof as written gives only *necessary* conditions (so possible overcount) due to the [(unnecessary) use of unidirectional arrows.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a242%20unidirectional) This is a common mistake made by beginners, so one should strive to write exemplary answers that  avoid such pitfalls.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Happier now?

Comment: But the same critique applies elsewhere in the argument, e.g. "we know that". What *precisely* does that mean, it is $\Rightarrow$ or $\iff?$  To be rigorous *all* of the arrows need to be bidirectional, or else you need to explicitly check that all of the possible candidate solutions are actual solutions. Readers not familiar with these pitfalls can learn by following the links in my prior comment.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I think that your concern is excessive. It’s also important that students learn to read and understand mathematics as it is commonly written.

Comment: No doubt there are plenty of "commonly written" texts which include such pedagogical blunders. But here we should strive for much higher quality exposition.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to find the number of solutions.

$k$ such that $(k+1)$ or $(k-1)$ is divisible by $7$ and $k>1$.

Note that $7n+1 < 7\cdot 669+1=4684$
Therefore, $k<69$

Every $k$ such that $(k+1)$ or $(k-1)$ is divisible by $7$ and $69>k>1$ will give you a solution.

Therefore, $k = 6,13,20,...62$ These are $\frac{62-6}{7}+1 = 9$ numbers

or $k = 8,15,22,...,64$ These are $\frac{64-8}{7}+1 = 9$ numbers
$9+9=18$ solutions